# Nuxt 3 throw createError not reaching the custom error page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

I am settting up an auth middleware which runs just fine, however when I am creating the error I just get to the default error page. I need to reach the custom ~/error.vue to insert a button to click clearError()

Docs says I can just add an error component in the source, which I did.
If ~/error.vue is not reachable from ~/server/middleware then how can I call clearError() in the default error page?

*in ~/server/midddleware/auth/auth.ts*

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
 if(conditionNotMet){
  throw createError({
    statusCode: 404,
    name: 'NotFoundError',
    message: 'Todo not found',
    statusMessage: "Not Found",
  })
 }
}
```

*~/error.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div>{{ props.error }}</div>
</template>
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps(['error'])
</script>
```

This is what I see instead

[image: question error sample]

https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling

Comment: How did you resolve this ? 

Comment: @jremi i did not. i gave up and decided to ditch the middleware and respond back a 404, then handle the response on client. So frustrating

Comment: Yes, i did the same thing. Super unusual behavior.